# What is the new way of checking "callable" methods in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I was studying introspection in Python, and as I was getting through basic examples, I found out that the `callable` built-in function is no longer available in Python 3.1.

How can I check if a method is callable now?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if hasattr(f, "__call__"):
```

[What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

Answer (score 23):

The callable() builtin function from Py2.x was resurrected in python3.2.

Comment: Could you provide a usage ?

Comment: I could: `if callable(f): print('f is callable')` ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
isinstance(f, collections.Callable)
```

Comment: Not everything that can be called is an instance of collections.Callable.

Comment: @JasperBryant-Greene Do you have an example? The only thing I could find for which this doesn't work is Python 2 old-style classes (the class objects themselves, that is, not instances thereof), which don't exist in Python 3 anyway.